# Operators won't function in Calculatlor app for Android/Java

Tags: java, android, mobile

I just started my first semester in mobile development and run into some problems with the flow of my program.  I can understand the Java and how the logic of the program but I am having trouble implementing it.

What I have: buttons show number in TextView, can press operators, but calculate doesn't do anything.  My calculator is supposed to be a rolling calculator, i.e: INPUT: 1 + 1 = 2 (display/keep) + 1 (automatically display: 3); calculate (=) will most likely only be pressed once in a given sequence and operators will carry out that function instead.  firstNum + secondNum = result -> firstNum = secondNum, secondNum = 0 -> result??? Not sure

This is my MainActivity.java ; I have created resources for all my buttons and texts in strings.xml so I think those are fine.

```
      btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            operatorSwitch = 1;
            numPressed = false; // able to add numbers

            if(pressed){ // if this is not the first calculation:
                 // total becomes firstNum

                secondNum = Double.parseDouble(display); // secondNum is new input
                total = firstNum + secondNum; // calculate new total
                display = Double.toString(total);
                txtCalculation.setText(display);
                numPressed = true; // Can't add numbers to mess with current total

            }else{ // first calculation
                firstNum = Double.parseDouble(display);
                display = "";
                txtCalculation.setText(display);}
        }
    });



btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                secondNum = Double.parseDouble(display);
                while(pressed == false){
                if (operatorSwitch == 1) {
                    total = firstNum + secondNum;
                    display = Double.toString(total);
                    txtCalculation.setText(display);
                    pressed = true;
                    firstNum = total;
                    numPressed = true;
                }
```

edit: Just looking for pointers in the right direction and general flow of my code as I'm confusing myself already

edit2: I can't get my add function to work in my way, it adds the total constantly without allowing me to have a second input.